# Character Recognition in Image in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I would like to take an image, and index the words in that image, let the user search the image and then display the image highlighting around keywords.

So, what I need is an OCR class that takes an image and that gives me a list of words with their coordinates? Possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use  these projects

- [Tessnet2  (a .NET 2.0 Open Source OCR assembly using Tesseract engine)](http://www.pixel-technology.com/freeware/tessnet2/)
- [Tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) (An OCR Engine that was developed at HP Labs between 1985 and 1995... and now at Google)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with Microsoft Office Document Imaging 12.0 Type Library.

Sample: [Converting Images to Text using Office 2007 OCR, OpenXML and Speech Recognition](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/OCRSampleApplication.aspx)